# How to pass a complex object between pages in a Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, windows-store-apps

What is the best approach in passing a complex object between Pages in a Windows Store App? In the MSDN it states that only basic types of objects can be passed in order to serialize the session state, but I don't intend to serialize session state since my app will just log out and ask for log in credentials when the app is launched the next time. I plan to serialize my data when the user either hits the log out or save buttons.

Comment: can you provide what code that you have thus far perhaps we could lend you some direction from there once we see what your logical thought process looks like in terms of source code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you are passing a Person object to the PersonDetailPage. Then here is what you would have on your MainPage (or any other page).

Assuming that you are working with a GridView:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PersonDetailPage), (Person)e.ClickedItem);
```

Then on the PersonDetailPage, on the LoadState() you will verifiy if a parameter was passed, and then atribute that parameter to a variable.

```
protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
      if (navigationParameter != null)
      {
           person = (Person)navigationParameter;
      }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to pass objects of different types, how would this work? Say I want to keep my Person all the way to page 3 of my app, so that I could serialize all the data on that page. How could I go about that?

Comment: I actually found an answer to my comment. Using what you posted I went with passing a Tuple with 2 objects. Seems like an "Ok" approach but if you have any better solution I am all ears! Thanks!!

Comment: The only reason I came up with the solution above was because you aren't serializing session state. I don't think it is the best solution, but you could verify if the navigationParameter is a "Person" or a "Dog".

e.j: 

`if (navigationParameter != null)
`{
`if (navigationParameter is Person)
  `{
    `person = (Person)navigationParameter;
  `}
  `else if (navigationParameter is Dog)
  `{
    `dog = (Dog)navigationParameter;
  `}
`}

I don't think that is the best solution you can come up with, but it was what I had in mind today.

Comment: Thanks anyway! It pointed me somewhere in the direction I wanted to go for now, will probably try to develop something in the realm of what Damir suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Not serializing the session state could result in a suboptimal experience for your user. If you only save the state when the user logs out, it will loose state when the application suspends and is terminated by the OS because of low resources.

Take a look at [the application lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx): as soon as the user switches to another application and your application is not in front any more, it is going to be suspended - this is your last opportunity to save the state and preserve it. Although your application can be left in memory until the user switches back, it can as well happen that the OS will shut it down if it needs resources. In this case the user will have to restart it. If you don't save your state when the application is suspended, you will loose it and the user experience will suffer.

Although you can probably come up with a custom way of preserving the state, I do suggest you stick with passing only basic type between pages which are supported by Windows runtime. This way you can take advantage of [SuspensionManager](http://www.damirscorner.com/UsingSuspensionManagerForSavingApplicationState.aspx) included in the application templates which takes care of most of the work. It's not that difficult to pass only basic types between pages. It's probably best you only pass object ids (unique identifiers of some sort) and keep the objects somewhere else where they can be accessed by all pages. Alternatively you could make your objects serializable and pass them as serialized strings (either XML or JSON).

Comment: The app I am developing has a custom Log In page that when the user switches to another app or suspends it, the user will have to log back into the app. This will not go into the Windows Store App, will mostly be used for in-house purposes. My objects are being created after the user successfully logs into the app by deserializing an xml file that is stored in LocalFolder. I understand your approach and will try to create your object ids approach, seems much cleaner! Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @em007 In your scenarion I'd probably try to go with the standard approach I just describeed, with the only difference of displaying the login page first and only returning him to his previously saved state after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your complex object, pass it as a string then deserialize the string at the second page